# How to make a query returning pages from multiple parents

Tags: wp-query, customization, children

I'd like to make a query that returns the children pages of various parent pages.

Unfortunately the `post_parent` attribute of `WP_Query` accepts only one value.

What do you suggest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST does not have parents, but categories. Only PAGE can have parent. So, the question is, what do you want to get?

In case of getting POSTS from different categories, just use [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and add multiple categories.

As for pages, just use [`get_page_children`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children).

Comment: Sorry I meant "pages" not "posts", the "post" in "post_parent" got me confused.. get_page_children is what I need indeed, thanks!